# How I can prove that $T$ is well defined and continuous such that we have :$\|T\|\leq \|g\|_q,$ $T(f)=\int_\Omega f\overline{g}\,d\mu$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

**Exercice:** let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measurable space, $p\in[1,+\infty[$ and let $g\in L^q(\Omega)$ with $q$ is the conjugate exponent of $p,$ let $T$ such that $T:L^p(\Omega)\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $T(f)=\int_\Omega f\overline{g}\,d\mu$, I want to prove that $T$ is well defined and continious such that we have :$\|T\|\leq \|g\|_q$ ?

**My Attempt:** I have tried to reformualte the Holder inequality like this :

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\Omega}f\bar{g} \,d\mu & \leq & \left(\int_\Omega f^p \, d\mu\right)^{1/p} \left(\int_\Omega \bar{g}^q \, d\mu\right)^{1/q}\\
&\leq&\|f\|_p\|\bar{g}\|_q
\end{eqnarray*}
Now $\|f\|_p\|\bar{g}\|_q$ is finite implies that $T$ is defined , for continuity I have used the fact that $T$ is measurable implies that is continious , But my problem how I can show that $\|T\|\leq \|g\|_q$ , I have used the assumption $1\leq p <q < \infty$ implies $\ell^p\subset \ell^q$ which prove the result , But am not care about this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not realted to $\ell^{p}$ spaces (which are different from $L^{p}$ spaces). You don't need $p<q$ for this.

You already know (by Holder's inequality) that $|Tf|\leq \|f\|_p \|g\|_q$. [ Note that $|\overline {g}|=|g|$ so you can drop the conjugate].

A linear map $T$ from one normed linear  space $X$ to another normed linear  space $Y$ is continuous iff it is bounded in the sense $\|Tx\| \leq C\|x\|$ for some finite constant $C$. By definition $\|T\|$ is the infiumum  of all such constants $C$. Hence, taking $C=\|g\|_q$,  $T$ is bounded in our case and $\|T\| \leq \|g\|_q$.

Comment: Pleas could u show me what is the difference between  $\ell^{p}$ and $L^{p}$ to avoid mixing between the two notation ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik $\ell^{p}$ is the space of sequences $(a_n)$  such that $\sum |a_n|^{p} <\infty$. $L^{p}$ is defined w.r.t. a given measure $\mu$ and it is defined as the space of all measurable functions $f$ with $\int |f|^{p} d\mu <\infty$. The inclusion $\ell^{p} \subset \ell^{q}$ holds for $p <q$ but there is no such relation between $L^{p}$ and $L^{q}$ in general. If $\mu$ is a finite measure we have the opposite inclusion: $L^{q} \subset L^{p}$ for $p <q$!

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Note also that the statement: "measurable implies continuous" is not true.